# I have to write a program that calculates and displays the total score using a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm quite new to the for loops in Python. So, I want to write a program that asks the user to enter to enter 20 different scores and then I want the program to calculate the total and display it on the screen. How could I use a for loop to do this?
edit: I can ask the user to for the different numbers but I don't know how to then add them.

Comment: Have you tried *nothing?!*

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: You can either add them as they are entered or you could place them into an array. This would allow you to use the data for other things later, like finding the highest and lowest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving you the full code here is the pseudocode for what your code should look like

```
x = ask user for input
loop up till x //Or you could hard code 20 instead of x
    add user input to a list
end
total = sum values in list
print total
```

Here are all the things you need to implement the logic

**User input/output:**
http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html

**Loops:**
https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

**Summing a list:**
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
total = 0;   # create the variable
for i in range(1,20): # iterate over values 1 to 20 as a list
     total += int(input('Please enter number {0}: '.format(i)));

print("Sum of the numbers is '{0}'".format(total))
```

I'd suggest you go through the tutorials on the python site:

- Python 3 is here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html
- Python 2 is here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

I could go into a lot of detail here and explain everything, however I'd only be duplicating the resources already available. Written far better than I could write them. It would be far more beneficial for you (and anyone else reading this who has a similar issue) to go through these tutorials and get familiar with the python documentation. These will give you a good foundation in the basics, and show you what the language is capable of.

## Input

To read a value from the commandline you can use the `input` function, e.g. `valueString = input("prompt text")`. Notice the value stored is of type string, which is effectively an array of ASCI/Unicode characters.

So in order to perform math on the input, you first need to convert it to its numerical value - `number = int(valueString)` does this. So you can now add numbers together.

## Adding numbers

Say you had two numbers, `num1` and `num2`, you can just use the addition operator. For example `num3 = num1 + num2`. Now suppose you have a for loop and want to add a new number each time the loop executes, you can use the `total += newNum` operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
total = 0

for _ in range(1,20):
    num = input('> ')
    total += int(num)

print(total)
```

I hope this helps.